# Construct an explicit bijection from [x], the equivalence class of x, to Q.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Define a relation $ \sim $ on the set of real numbers as follows: For $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ : $x \sim  y$  if  $ −∈\mathbb{Q}$

I have proven that this is an equivalence class:

**Reflexitivity**

$x - x = 0$

$0 \in \mathbb{Q}$

so $x\sim x$

**Symmetry**

$x - y = a$, where $a \in \mathbb{Q}$

$y - x = -a$, where $-a \in \mathbb{Q}$

so $x \sim y, y \sim x$

**Transitive**

$x - y = a$, $a \in \mathbb{Q}$,

$y - z = b$, $z \in \mathbb{R}$, $b \in \mathbb{Q}$

$x - y + y - z = a + b$

$= x - z = a + b$

$= x - z = c$, $c \in \mathbb{Q}$

Thus, $x \sim y$ is an equivalence relation. However, I am having trouble finding the equivalence class of $x$ and most importantly, how to construct an explicit bijection from the equivalence class, $[x]$, to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: You know that for every representative of an equivalence class, say $\left[ x \right]$, and any $y \in \left[ x \right]$, we will always have $x - y \in \mathbb{Q}$. Once you fix the representative, $x - y$ will be uniquely determined. Moreover, this will be the precise bijection.

Comment: $[x]=\{x+q:q\in\Bbb Q\}$, so the map $[x]\to\Bbb Q:y\mapsto y-x$ is a bijection.